# Tell the version of Windows XP (64-bits or 32-bits)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

My laptop's CPU is the Intel P8600 (x86-64 architecture), and Dell pre-installed Windows XP SP3 on it.

However I am not sure if the version of Windows XP is the 64-bit version or the 32-bit version; can someone tell me how to find out the answer?

I am asking this because I want to install a proper JRE with good performance on my system.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you have no idea whether your installation of XP is 32 or 64 bit, it's 32 bit. You would notice XP-64 as you wouldn't have any drivers for anything :-)

Comment: Also, easiest way in my humble opinion is to open Windows Explorer, go to the C: drive, and check if there's a `Program Files (x86)` folder. If there is, that's 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 13):

from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218

**Windows XP**

If you have Windows XP, there are two methods to determine whether you are running a 32-bit or a 64-bit version. If one does not work, try the other.

**Method 1: View System Properties in Control Panel**

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. Type `sysdm.cpl`, and then click OK.
3. Click the General tab. The operating system is displayed as follows:

   - For a 64-bit version operating system: Windows XP Professional x64 Edition Version (year) appears under System.
   - For a 32-bit version operating system: Windows XP Professional Version (year) appears under System.

**Method 2: View System Information window**

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. Type `winmsd.exe`, and then click OK.
3. When System Summary is selected in the navigation pane, locate Processor under Item in the details pane. Note the value.

   - If the value that corresponds to Processor starts with x86, the computer is running a 32-bit version of Windows.
   - If the value that corresponds to Processor starts with ia64 or AMD64, the computer is running a 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Start>Run then type

```
cmd /K if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64. (echo "64-bit".) ELSE echo "32-bit"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know, its 32 (64-bit windows xp pro says "Windows XP 64 Bit Edition" or similar for 64, there is no 32 bit Home)

You can check here:
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=827218